# Can't run created command on Laravel Scheduler locally

Tags: laravel, command, scheduler

I'm trying to run created command locally, but when hitting php artisan schedule:work it shows no sceduled commands are ready to run. What's wrong?

My Kernel:

```
    protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\AddEntry',
    ]; 

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('add:entry')->everyMinute();
    }
```

I also edited AppServiceProvider

```
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
```

Command itself is working and it's visible on php artisan list

Comment: does `php artisan add:entry` runs perfectly??

Comment: yes, I tested more than one time

Comment: then this is probably some cache issue. clear the cache and try again.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question description but I tried to remove caches: route:cache, config:cache, config:clear, view:clear

Comment: do you have any overlapping?

Comment: As I know I dont' have one, but I can't ensure 100%